Why is $E(\sqrt{|x|}) = \int{\sqrt{|x|}}f(x) dx$?
Here is a problem I came across:
problem, and I've got the solution here: solution for part (iv)
I want to know why, for the last part, $$E(\sqrt{|x|}) = \int{\sqrt{|x|}}f(x) dx$$
instead of $$E(\sqrt{|x|}) = \int{\sqrt{|x|}}f(\sqrt{|x|}) dx$$

It comes from the definition of expectation

The $E$ notation means an integral with respect to an (implied) probability measure $P.$ In your problem it appears that this is a probability measure on $\mathbb R$ or a subset of $\mathbb R,$ and that it is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure. Absolute continuity implies the existence of a density function $f\geq0$ with the property that for every measurable subset $A$ of $\mathbb R$
$$P(A)=\int_{x\in A}f(x)dx.$$
An integral with respect to $P$ is usually defined as a limit of linear combinations of probabilities $\sum\alpha_iP(A_i)$, so by linearity the expression $f(x)$ survives into the integral that defines $E.$
